# Flair images low resolution on retina displays

Tags: feature-request, design, flair

<sub>(Please note, this question was re-written in 2023)</sub>

An oft-overlooked feature SO has, is the ability to generate a flair *image* for your user profile.

You can find the page for them, here:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/

Here are some rendered examples:

[image: default]
[image: dark]
[image: hotdog (why?)]

Please note that these images are actually *generated png files*, and not just plain HTML.

This feature is quite old already, and as such, has gotten a bit outdated.

On modern screens, there's two significant issues with the generated images:

- They use an old UI design.
- They're *tiny*, which means most browsers will upscale the images, making them blurry.

  - (No support for retina scaling)

What I would like to request is:

- Update the flair design so it's in line with the site's current design.
- Add support for larger images (double / quadruple scale, for example).
- Add support for SVG output; This would make theming a lot easier, and they're infinitely scalable.

Comment: Imagine it being half the resolution you see and all blocky. That describes the experience well.

Comment: "the ability to generate a flair image for your user profile." - does this image appear anywhere in the Stack UI by default? I can't find where. If not, then what actually is the intended purpose? What do you mean by "for your user profile"?

Comment: You can embed it elsewhere to link to your profile.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: The intended purpose is probably to use the image on other websites/forums/signatures

Comment: Okay, I understood after some further investigation/observation. You find this in the stack UI by going to your user page, then choosing "Settings" from the top bar, then choosing "Flair" under the "Site Settings" header in the left-side menu; and the presumed purpose is as @BDL says. So, why not... *say this* in the question? That makes it a lot easier to understand what you're referring to. As you say, the feature is oft-overlooked; it's not hard to understand why.

Comment: Wat... I linked to it. Why do I need to add the path to get there if there's a direct link? I mean, open the link, see it's in "settings"...

Comment: And in regards to _"presumed purpose"_: The flair page even states as much: _"It’s a piece of valuable flair™ you can place on any website to show off your user profile!"_

Comment: It looks like someone has previously made a prototype of the improved version: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422307/18248018 :D

Comment: related: [Have a higher-resolution flair for printing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130607/997587), [Optimise Stack Exchange user flair for Retina displays](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131045/997587), [SVG Flairs (In Addition To PNG Flairs)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65759/997587)

Answer (score 6):

While we're rebuilding it... it'd be neat if we could configure the flair, deciding between other interesting things to include in it. For example, a limited number of specific badges, collective icons, mod status, etc

Comment: Mod status is already indicated in the site-specific flair (it's a diamond next to the username). I'm not sure how it would work on the combined flair, since some mods have many diamonds.