# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results - now with two more mods!

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

[Moderator election #14](https://stackoverflow.com/election/14) on Stack Overflow has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: sideshowbarker]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

On 15 December 2022, we called up the two runners-up to be moderators.

[image: blackgreen]
[image: Henry Ecker]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/14) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4819670275194880). For results of the election with three seats available, you can view the [updated summary report on Opavote](https://www.opavote.com/results/6753741024788480)

Comment: Congratulations sideshowbarker!

Comment: Congrats sideshowbarker!  Thank you to everyone who nominated themselves and took the time to write out responses to the questions.  You are all appreciated whether you have a little diamond or not.

Comment: Very good finish for Daniel Widdis too, who defeated the spectre of reputation / candidate score.

Comment: Congrats sideshowbarker! A surprisingly strong round of candidates this year.

Comment: @blackgreen where can I find information about it?

Comment: @holydragon if you mean the results, see the two links in the last line of the question.

Comment: For the candidates who didn't get elected: You are also excellent! You have already contributed a lot to the Stack Overflow family. Fellows like you encourage young programmers like me to get involved in open-source communities.

Comment: Congrats and thanks for taking the time to do this!

Comment: Damn my CORS rival is a moderator :D it amazing how few ppl properly understand CORS properly and a fellow barker username so Gratz @sideshowbarker

Comment: Congratulations  @sideshowbarker

Comment: Congratulations blackgreen and Henry Ecker!

Comment: How is it we go from *we only need one mod* to *we need three mods* in a months time?  People might not have nominated when they though only one slot was up for grabs.  Having three slots announced from the beginning might have brought in more people to begin with.

Comment: @NathanOliver [CGPT happened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/6296561). The flag load it's been generating was unsustainable. We couldn't have predicted that in advance, and as previously mentioned several times in both chat and on meta, participation trends did not support a three slot election. No one could've predicted an AI would be released, and generate enormous amounts of additional work due to it being abused to the point where additional slots suddenly became necessary

Comment: @NathanOliver Chicken or the egg problem. If we knew there would be more good candidates willing to participate in the election then maybe we would have requested more slots.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine If it's related to just ChatGPT then I get that.  I haven't seen anything about how much more mod time has been needed to deal with it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Here's the gist of it then: We get a few hundred CGPT flags per day, leading to hundreds or even thousands of post deletions per day. There's often one flag per user (not accounting overlap from several users), but each flag can lead to anywhere between a couple and tens of deletions per user. According to CMs, we are getting the vast majority of the posts, but the amount of work poured in to achieve that is exorbitant, even by the normal SO volume. CGPT users are dealt with in the same way as plagiarists; all posts (at least after CGPT's release) have to be checked

Comment: and because it's an ongoing event, and CGPT offers unnecessarily high answer rates, these flags are urgent and get prioritised. If a CGPT answerer isn't stopped early, the workload that user causes generally always increases. We're calling up mods because we need to stay on top of it, as well as all the other usual flags

Comment: Well, that didn't take long. I guess we could as well add all the other candidates as well. Why wait for 6 to 8 weeks between adding them ....

Comment: @GertArnold no. We don't unelect moderators. Elected moderators, whether directly elected or called up, are permanently elected. (Except on beta sites, but we're not a beta site so that  doesn't apply)

Comment: Here's an idea: Use chatgpt as a mod. It's time we got that AI smurf working for us.

Comment: Wonder if we can add "temporary" moderators for say 4-12 weeks.  Possible rewards for such service: 1. Hands on experience. 2. Those who worked temporary can get reviews from other moderators for future elections.

Comment: @user4581301 its a bot for generating believable text. I'd rather put it to work explaining downvotes eloquently.

Answer (score 100):

Welcome to the team! One position with a lot of qualified candidates, you deserve it.

Not a lot of flags to process today.

[image]

Dang! Those are *meta* flags. Here are the main site flags

[image]

If you could handle one or two thousands of those that would be a good start. No sweat, you have all week.

Welcome again !

Comment: Or all of them. Kthx in advantaged!

Comment: Well, at least you didn't mention how many of them are plagiarism flags. Oh, wait...

Answer (score 86):

Congratulations sideshowbarker! Welcome to the team!

As usual, we saved some flags for you:

[image]
<sub>(Image by Alan Levine; copyright 2013; [from flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/cogdog/9090734632/in/photostream/); licensed under [CC BY 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/))</sub>

There was a really good field of candidates this year. Thank you to each of you for nominating yourself. Your willingness to take on the burden of being a moderator is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 38):

I happened to stop by today and have just found out that you're a moderator now, [11 years to the day after I was elected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287870/november-2011-community-moderator-election-results). Congratulations! I have fond memories of the illuminating conversations we had back in the day — I learned a lot from you from your work on web standards, and I wanted to say thanks. Knowing you I have no doubt you'll be a great addition to the team and you'll be able to handle what's about to get thrown your way. Good luck! <sup><sub>you might need just a little bit</sub></sup>

Answer (score 36):

*I'm sorry, normally I'd finish by leaving an upvote and sending my congrats to the chat, but there **really** aren't enough congratulatory posts here! So...*

## Congratulations sideshowbarker ♦!

#### Fun fact: You are the first moderator to get elected in an election that has only one position available! A well-deserved win!

*<sub>Greyed out or tinted in pink, t'is still congratulations written in ink!</sub>*

Answer (score 36):

Congratulations and welcome to the team to both blackgreen and Henry Ecker too!

We still have lots more flags to handle:

[image]
<sub>Image credit: by unknown; copyright 2017 or earlier; license CC0; from [pxhere.com](https://pxhere.com/en/photo/423441)</sub>

Comment: In spirit of the AI: Is that image real or generated? That would have been a silly question a year ago but today it is a vital skill for an SO mod ... Congrats to the new hands on deck.

Comment: Real, generated, it's all the same old garbage.

Comment: I can confirm that it is real. I recognize my spam flags up there to the left, in a black plastic bag. SO never had any problems generating massive amounts of garbage without the help of an AI :)

Answer (score 13):

Congratulations to all of you and thanks again for reducing the pile ;)
As a small reward I offer you a vector version of your flairs to have a clearer rendering of your stats:

[image: user:441757's SO profile]

[image: user:4108803's SO profile]

[image: user:15497888's SO profile]

These are dynally generated using the [stackoverflow-readme-profile](https://stackoverflow-readme-profile.vercel.app/) project.

Comment: But it [isn't spelled "Stackoverflow"](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/). Can it be fixed, please?

Comment: It's true but I'm used to name my OS projects according to the GitHub repository slug :) the official term is "Stack Overflow" righ ?